# Irish expression - come with your hands hanging

Tags: idioms

South Ireland Cork-Kerry border Shliabh Luachra "don't come with your hands hanging"

> *“We'll be right over ... Can we bring anything?”*
> *“No thanks. As the Irish say, '**Just come with your hands hanging**'"*
> [<sub>Source - MacDonald Coyote: A Search for Heaven in the High Sierra</sub>](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22come%20with%20your%20hands%20hanging%22)

Comment: Sorry, what's the question you have?

Comment: *"Just come empty-handed"* - you don't need to bring anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.